# WriteObject<T> in XNA with existing ContentWriters

Tags: xna, xna-content-pipeline

I have quite a lot of custom content pipeline components, and I was just wondering if under the hood XNA knows about these things when doing its magic...

Here is my scenario.

I have animation objects which basically contain 2d animation frames and timings etc, which can be loaded as self contained objects or can be embedded within other object. Now I was expecting that my CustomObjectAWriter could contain an instance to AnimationObjectAWriter and internally just call through to that to write out each animation object, i.e:

```
<SomeCustomObjectA>
    <SomeCustomElementA>
        ...
    </SomeCustomElementA>
    <SomeCustomElementB>
        ...
        <AnimationObjectA>
            ...
        </AnimationObjectA>
    </SomeCustomElementB>
</SomeCustomObjectA>
```

However as AnimationObjectAWriter has its Write method protected I am unable to access it, however I was wondering if WriteObject will know of the AnimationObjectAWriter so if I did `WriteObject<AnimationObjectA>(animationObjectAInstance)` would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that will work, although if it's just simple XML->objects you probably don't need custom writers/readers at all.

See: [Automatic XNB serialization in XNA Game Studio 3.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906024925/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/03/25/automatic-xnb-serialization-in-xna-game-studio-3-1.aspx)

See also: [Shawn Hargreaves Blog Index: Content Pipeline](http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html#contentpipeline)

Comment: it is xml but it is not in the xna content format as it is used for non XNA frameworks too, and it is not a simple 1-1 mapping like XNA prefers, but thanks for the answer.